# Make Done button on softkeyboard close dialog android

Tags: android

new to android.

How can I dismiss a dialog box when user click on Done button on the softkeyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For your `EditText` do : `edt.setOnKeyListener(this);`

and in your `Activity` do :

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        dismissDialog();
    }
return true;
}
```

OR

```
    edt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
    @Override
    void onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            dismissDialog();
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Im using setOnEditorActionListener on my editText, which work well if I want to display a toast or whatever. How can I trigger the dialog box PositiveButton function in it?

Comment: dismissDialog(); is telling me 'deprecated'

Comment: you need to write your own code there man

Comment: Thats my question, how do I call the dialog box positiveButton function within the setOnEditorListener

Comment: you can get the `dialog` object and then do `dialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to get IME_ACTION for done button.

```
private class OnMyEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```